# Should both HTTP and HTTPS sites be kept listed in Google search console after migration to HTTPS?

Tags: https, http

So, I have site which has been migrated from HTTP to HTTPS. Somehow my webmasters account has both the sites listed in there. My question is if I should keep the HTTPS in the webmasters and delete the HTTP property from it?

Also, my GA account has only HTTP version of the site, is it incorrect? and is it wise to delete the properties from both GA and Search Console and start over so as to keep things clean.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your http site in Search Console and use the Change of Address tool. This can take awhile but when possible, you should select the preferred url which is your https.

With Google Analytics you can go into your Admin and change the URL. As long as the UA code is still the same you will continue to see data. You can add an annotation to the graph and segment by dates if you want to track the difference in numbers.

Unfortunately I don't have an answer for your webmasters account, hopefully someone else will.

Comment: Thanks GrapeSoda for the answer. I actually did change the http to https in the View settings of the Account and its working fine now, I can actually see https related landing pages in organic search reports.  As for the webmasters, I think I ll keep both and have linked GA to the https account.